# How to export apache-ignite metrics to sql/jmx

Tags: prometheus, ignite, jmx-exporter

i would like to export the apache ignite-2.8.1 node/cluster/cache metrics to sql and graffana over JMX.
so that i can monitor on the ignite performance and alerting.

I tried with the jmx_exporter
https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter.
But getting below error.

```
Jul 16, 2020 5:00:24 PM io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector collect
SEVERE: JMX scrape failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to javax.management.Attribute
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.scrapeBean(JmxScraper.java:160)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.doScrape(JmxScraper.java:117)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.collect(JmxCollector.java:473)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:190)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:223)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:144)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22)
        at 

    io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer$HTTPMetricHandler.handle(HTTPServer.java:68)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and used below apache-ignite-exproter
https://github.com/leonardonsantos/apache-ignite-exporter

Let me know where i am missing the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Use official Apache Ignite JMX exporter that captures metrics of the new monitoring subsystem introduced in Ignite 2.8: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/new-metrics

Also, consider GridGain Control Center as a preferred monitor ing and management tool of your cluster. It supports all basic metrics, alerts, tracing and much more: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/overview